# How to properly authorize request to Google Cloud Storage API?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Storage JSON API to retrieve files from a bucket using http calls.

I am curling from a Container in GCE within the same project as the storage bucket, and the service account has read access to the bucket

Here is the pattern of the requests:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket}/{object}
```

According to the API console, I don't need anything particular as the service account provides Application Default Credentials. However, I keep having this:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get
```

I also tried to create an API key for the project and appended it to the url (`https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket}/{object}?key={key}`)but I still got the same 401 error.

How can I authorize requests to query this API?

Comment: are you using kubernetes? or is it just compute engine?

Comment: Kubernetes on GKE

Answer (score 4):

The URL that you are using is not correct. The APIs use a URL that starts with `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b`.

Using API keys is not recommended. Instead you should use a `Bearer: token`. I will show both methods.

To get an access token for the gcloud default configuration:

`gcloud auth print-access-token`

Then use the token in your `curl` request. Replace TOKEN with the token from the gcloud command.

To list buckets:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b

curl https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?key=APIKEY
```

To list objects:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/examplebucket/o

curl https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/examplebucket/o?key=APIKEY
```

[API Reference: List Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list)

Comment: Thanks. I came accross `gcloud auth print-access-token` but it only produces a short lived token. I am using this API within a GCP project and I would like to avoid having to implement a whole Oauth flow.

Comment: All access tokens are short lived. Generating access tokens is fairly easy. then you authorize another one before it expires. Your other choice is to use the SDK and service account credentials - which are designed for your use case. However, you are changing the question - create a new one.

Comment: Additional item, when you use curl, your credentials are not being used. Only what you specify to curl is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to create another cluster you can obtain permission like this:
Click in "avanced edit"
[image: first]
next click in "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs"
[image: second]

And that's it :D